# Issues installing ffmpeg on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04

```
apt install ffmpeg

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
> information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may
> mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
> 
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  ffmpeg : Depends:
> libavcodec58 (= 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1.1)
>           Depends: libavdevice58 (= 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>           Depends: libavfilter7 (= 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1.1)
>           Depends: libavformat58 (= 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>           Depends: libavresample4 (= 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>           Depends: libavutil56 (= 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>           Depends: libpostproc55 (= 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>           Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.9) but it is not going to be installed
>           Depends: libswresample3 (= 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>           Depends: libswscale5 (= 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1.1) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
> broken packages. root@vmi485211:/usr/local/centovacast/liquidsoap#
> ffmpeg --version ffmpeg: command not found
```

Comment: Welcome back to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have debian repository (buster 10) in your sources.list which break your configuration.

Edit your sources.list:

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

or

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

as follows:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```